# RoR: Add property to object when found in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Here is my controller:

```
def show
  @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  @investments = Investment.where(:portfolio => @portfolio.id)
end
```

Which will display the portfolio and the multiple investments for that portfolio. The investments, in the database, have the following properties:

ID,Ticker, Quantity, Portfolio ID

What I am looking to do is get the price of the investment, which I have gotten through an api as follows:

```
def get_nav
  nav_url = 'http://navs.xignite.com/v2/xNAVs.xml/GetNAV?IdentifierType=Symbol&Identifier=' + ticker + '&_TOKEN=' + XIGNITE_TOKEN
  require 'open-uri'
  nav_doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(nav_url))
  nav_value = nav_doc.css('NAV').first.content.to_f
end
```

where `ticker` will need to be the `investment.ticker` variable in the investment and then `nav_value` will be the stock price, to be stored as `investment.price`. What I am looking to do is to have this in the `show` view:

```
<% @investment.each do |i| %>
  Stock: <%= i.ticker %><br>
  Price: <%= i.price %>
<% end %>
```

What do I need to put in the model to make this happen? Where do I put the `get_nav` function?

Comment: use a decorator/presenter, use a lib like draper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just code it as a method in the Investment class.  Use an instance variable `@price` which will help you avoid hitting the API twice if you use `price` in a subsequent calculation. The reference to `ticker` should work fine as it's already an attribute in the object.

```
class Investment
  def price
    return @price if @price
    nav_url = 'http://navs.xignite.com/v2/xNAVs.xml/GetNAV?IdentifierType=Symbol&Identifier=' + ticker + '&_TOKEN=' + XIGNITE_TOKEN
    require 'open-uri'
    nav_doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(nav_url))
    @price = nav_doc.css('NAV').first.content.to_f
  end
end
```

Comment: I was trying to mess with it as so, but never knew to put the line:     return .@price if .@price